# How to obtain discretized integral form of ODE initial value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems

Given is the ODE initial value problem

$$
\frac{d}{dt} x(t) = f(t, x(t)), \quad x(t_0) = x_0.
$$

By integrating we obtain

$$
x(t) = x_0 + F(t, x(t)) - F(t_0, x(t_0)) = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t} f(s, x(s))\,\mathrm{d}s.
$$

In order to solve the ODE numerically on $[t_0, t_f]$, we use a grid $G = \{t_0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_f \}$, so we have

$$
x(t_{i+1}) = x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^{t_{i+1}} f(s, x(s)) \,\mathrm{d}s \tag{1}
$$

and by applying a arbitrary quadrature rule for the integral, we obtain a numerical scheme. However, I noticed that in most books it reads

$$
x(t_{i+1}) = x(t_i) + \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} f(s, x(s)) \,\mathrm{d}s \tag{2}
$$

instead. Did I miss something? Or can I derive (2) from (1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just because integration is additive for subdivisions of the integration interval.
\begin{align}
x(t_{i+1}) &= x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^{t_{i+1}} f(s, x(s)) \,\mathrm{d}s \tag{1}
\\
&=x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^{t_i
} f(s, x(s)) \,\mathrm{d}s + \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} f(s, x(s)) \,\mathrm{d}s
\\
&=x(t_i) + \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} f(s, x(s))
\end{align}

This motivation is not really helpful for more than the first and second order Runge-Kutta methods. With linear multi-step methods one can go a little farther with the integral form, but usually the methods are constructed using Taylor series and B-series enumerated by Butcher trees.